# JDK 7 под 32-разрядную версию Windows

Tags: windows, java

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, а существует ли jdk7 под 32-разрядную версию Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Это? [jdk7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html)

см. Windows x86